# Shouldn't the verb be in the third person?

Tags: grammar

I came across this book

> It's Not the Big That Eat the Small...It's the Fast That Eat the Slow

and my question is why **eat** is not **eats** ?

Thank you very much

Comment: The big, the small, the fast, the slow are all *plurals* :)

Comment: More accurately, _the big, the small_ etc are 'adjectival nouns' (assuming they've standardised terminology by now), adjectives pressed into service as nouns. How adjectival they remain or how nouny they have become is a matter for debate. They usually refer to a class of people etc, and though of single form, then take plural agreement. 'The poor are with you always.' Note exceptions, however 'People, on tasting the new wine, say "The old is better".'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oerkelens' comment answers this. Big, Small, Fast, and Slow are all plural words in this context.

Comment: Yes.  It is "the big fish that eat the small fish".  Or "the big corporations that eat the small corporations".  And so on.  Combining all these into one phrase: "The big that eat the small".

Comment: @GEdgar And the big fishes that eat the small fishes.